# What is the correct way to create slanted text in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, slanted

I need to write some romanized foreign words within a passage of English text. Generally, such words should appear as slanted text. I created this simple document and noticed that while both `\it` and `\empth` both slant the text, the appearance of the letters is quite different:

```
\starttext
    {\it Test}
    \emph{Test}
\stoptext
```

With the default fonts, the first example has a more rounded "e" and the start and end points of "s" end in with a small rounded shape, however, both texts appear slanted.

Which is the correct way to slant foreign-language text in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\it` is the font switch for italic, `\emph` is slanted by default but it is configurable. To change the default from slanted to italic, use:

```
\setupbodyfontenvironment
  [default]
  [em=italic]
```

For slanted use `\slanted{Test}` or the font switch `\sl`. However, it would
be better to use semantic markup instead of hard coding the style into your
document. Here's an example:

```
\definehighlight
  [foreign]
  [style=slanted]

\starttext
  Lorem ipsum \foreign{dolor sit amet}, consetetur.
\stoptext
```

[image: result]